# What is the difference between adjust-leading-to vs leader in Compass?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm learning Compass, I'm a little bit confused about 2 mixins: **adjust-leading-to** and **leader**. Can some one tell me the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adjust-leading-to` adjusts the line-height within a text block

`leader` adds whitespace (margin or padding) before a text block.

see: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/typography/vertical_rhythm/